# How to assign color value using plotly based on column value?

Tags: python, plotly

I am trying to plot k-means cluster using plotly, but i am having trouble in assigning colors based on there groups? I have following data frame.

[image]

group: cluster number

I am using this for scatter plot in plotly.

```py
clustered.iplot(kind='scatter',x='value1',y='value2', colors = {'[clustered['group']==1]':'green', '[clustered['group']==0]':'yellow'},mode='markers',size=10)
```

Its wrong because it will only get True and false for color dict object. How i can can associate these group values so that color of points appear differently in the plot.

Answer (score 3):

Instead of using `cufflinks` you can use the new Plotly Express library (https://plotly.express) to do this with:

```
px.scatter(clustered, x='value1', y='value2', color='group')
```

Answer (score 2):

If you only have two clusters, you can map the values:

```
clustered.iplot(kind='scatter', x='value1', y='value2', colors=clustered['group'].map({0:'yellow', 1:'green'}), mode='markers',size=10)
```

Comment: It didn't worked. i am getting this error `ValueError: The truth value of a Series is ambiguous. Use a.empty, a.bool(), a.item(), a.any() or a.all().`